# Special characters in dir command cmd not working

Tags: cmd

The command `dir ??p*p??.dll` gives me output like this:

[image: Real output]

I would expect it to return all files where the 3rd letter from the start and the 3rd letter from the end are a `p`.

Any ideas?

Comment: `??.*` would also match `x.x` as `?` matches the end of the name (or `.`).  Also consider `dir` looks at 8.3 names.  Use PowerShell `ls ??p*p??.dll` for the results you expect.

Comment: You could filter file names by the [`findstr` command](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html), like this: `dir /B /A:-D "??p*p??.dll" | findstr /I "^..p.*p..\.[^\.]*$"`

Answer (score 2):

As AlexK correctly states the wildcard character `?` matches the end or `.`

To have a correct result in cmd filter with (by default regex based) findstr.

In a RegEx the `.` is similar to `?` and `.*` (any number of dots) to wildcard `*`
`^` anchors at begin, `$` achors at the end. A literal dot has to be escaped `\.`

```
> dir /B "C:\windows\system32\??p*p??.dll" |findstr "^..p.*p..\.dll$
Apphlpdm.dll
AppointmentApis.dll
mfperfhelper.dll
SrpUxNativeSnapIn.dll
```